# Convert String to Date in Java is adding some extra minutes

Tags: java, date

I'm converting a string to Date in Java, but I having a problem It is adding some extra minutes to the result Date.

The String has the following format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss" and I have created this function:

```
public static Date parseISO8601(String date) {
    Date result = null;

    try {

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(date)) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    ISO8601_DATE_FORMAT);

            result = dateFormat.parse(date);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        return null;
    }
    return result;
}

public static final String ISO8601_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss";
```

When I use this function with this string  **"2015-06-11 20:17:56.873"** the result is **"Thu Jun 11 20:31:33 CST 2015"**. I am really new coding with Java, I have read a lot of posts but for me everything seems normal, I don´t know why this is happening.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

You are using 's' instead of 'S" for millis.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`, which uses "SSS" (milliseconds) instead of "sss" (seconds).

With a format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss` you are specifying the seconds field twice, so you are effectively trying to format a date-time of "2015-06-11 20:17:56 oh-wait-I-mean-873-seconds", which is why the resultant time is off by ~14 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss` with `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`

As per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

s --> second

S --> milliseconds